# Is it a weed or part of the aloe vera plant?

Tags: houseplants, plant-care, aloe

[image]

This was growing at the base of my aloe vera plant. I always remove weeds from the pot and I removed this as well thinking it's a weed. But it was so strong, it felt almost as if it was connected to the mother plant. I would like to know if that's indeed true or is this some really strong weed. Also am I supposed to remove weeds from the pots of my exotic plants?

PS-it's not a baby aloe, I've a healthy plant which give tons of babies so I know what they are supposed to be like. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Stick it in a pot on its own and see what it grows into. I've no idea what it is. It doesn't look like part of an aloe, but from the size of the root system it doesn't look like a typical weed that germinated from a seed in the compost either.

Comment: Are there palm trees nearby? My neighbors have a tree that rains seeds into my yard. The young sprouts look like that, sort of.

Comment: @Tim nevins Yes! Could be, there are variations palms around but at a moderate distance.. thanks!